# Mass Center in Corona SDK

Tags: coronasdk

I have an object of a fly, which is flying in the box. She's bumping into the walls and her speed is constant. But the main problem is that the fly is flying backwards sometimes. That's why I want to move the mass center but I don't know how! Could you help me? Or maybe you know how to make the fly to move right easier?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you want to make a it fly backwards along the x-axis , then change the `object:scale(-1,1)`

```
local star = display.newImage( "star.png" )

-- Flip the image horizontally
star:scale( -1, 1 )
```

I hope this may help you.